# Should all implementations of PBKDF2 generate the the same key from identical input?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, openssl, pbkdf2, cryptojs

I'm switching my node.js's application's hashing algorythms from the JS based [CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#PBKDF2) implementation to the node's own [crypto](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.1/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_callback) implementation.

Here is my implementation:

```
var password = "password1";
var salt = generateSalt();
var iterations = 4000;
var keySize = 768/32;
var cryptoJSKey = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, { "iterations": iterations , "keySize": keySize });
// base64 encoded key
cryptoJSKey = cryptoJSKey.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

require("crypto").pbkdf2( password, salt, iterations, keySize, function(err, derivedKey){
    var nodeCryptoKey = new Buffer( derivedKey, "binary" ).toString( "base64" );

    console.log( cryptoJSKey == nodeCryptoKey ); // always false!
});
```

One thing I noticed is that `nodeCryptoKey` ends up being `32` characters long and the cryptoJSKey is `192`. If I increase the `keySize` for only node's `crypto` version to `144` (`keySize * 6`) the key ends up being `192` characters long as well - though it is still different.

Am I doing something wrong or do the implementations just differ from one another?

Comment: Your code calls `require("crypto").pbkdf(` shouldn't that be `require("crypto").pbkdf2(`? Note the `2`. I would think that the results from version 1 and version 2 of PBKDF would be different.

Comment: You are right. That was just a typo in the question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.

In the rolled up PBKDF2.js script in "CryptoJS v3.0.2.zip" (the currently download) `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` is `undefined`; this was probably intended, but not something I noticed.

I was comparing node's Base64 encoded output to CryptoJS's hex output.

Another caveat was that the keySizes aren't compatible between CryptoJS and node.js. Node needs `keySize * 4` in order to output an identical key. I'm not familiar with what's going on under the hood in either case; but I'll just assume that's intended.

Node.js's PBKDF2's documentation is pretty scarce; it does, however, say its "key" parameter is named `keylen`, which is in bytes (or is it bits? I'm not sure).

Comment: Having just looked at the NodeJS documention in the crypto "packages" I don't think there is much to know for sure. It's even sparser than the PHP pages.